# Why IDE is not complaining when instead of a interface typed value you pass undefined?

Tags: typescript

I have this piece of code

```
interface A {
    z:string;
}

const b: { field: A } = {
    get field(){
        return undefined;
    }
}
```

an my IDE is not complaining of anything. Why so?
It should clearly not allow me to assign undefined.

But it works fine (complains) when I try to do this:

```
interface A {
    z:string;
}

const b: { field: A } = {
    get field(){
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: Throws as expected here. `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'A'.(2322)`

Comment: I can't reproduce this either.  Presumably something about your local environment is the cause, but we don't know anything about that.